# kernels with 16 registers instead of 32

Tags: cuda

**Question:**

Is there any advantage of using 16 registers instead of 32? If yes, is anywhere a suitable example?

**Background:**

It is well know that registers play a big role in occupancy, as occupancy may or may not affect efficiency (according to the algorithm).

On the other hand, devices of 6.1 computing capability are limited by 2048 active threads per SM and each SM has 65536 registers with a cap of 255 registers per thread. Thus more than 32 registers per thread must reduce the occupancy.

After warp shuffle, a lot of new possibilities with low lattency become available, so it is easier to use the whole warp (or part of it for 7.0 CC) as the minimal computing unit to avoid divergence and serialization in order to make a better use of the ALU. It makes easier to develop kernels with less than 32 registers.

Comment: nvidia claims that blocks from different kernels may be executed at the same time on a singe SMX. It might be that a kernel with small number of registers may allow simultaneous execution of another kernel with more registers.

Comment: It does make a lot of sense, but it does apply only if I have kernels that uses more registers and kernels that use less and they are not dependent or must be executed in a specific order...

So it is safe to assume that if the kernel does any required processing, of which the sucessing kernels are dependent, the best strategy is to use the 32 registers, since the resident warp cap will be the hard limit?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that there may be use-cases for which this feature is relevant. I don't know the context of your application(s).

Comment: Dear @FlorentDUGUET, I would like o say thanks for your answser, indeed it wont be helpful for my applications since it is kinda blunt processing... my best regards.
Also, I would like to encourage you to post your comment as an answer, since it really clarified my overthinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, NVIDIA claims that blocks from different kernels may be executed at the same time on a singe SMX (see slide 19 of [this](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf) presentation). It might be that a kernel with small number of registers may allow simultaneous execution of another kernel with more registers.